# How do I remove contacts on my sim card on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sim

By accident I imported some contacts to my contacts app in my iPhone. I do not need them there. So, If I need to avoid to import them again  by accident I would like to remove them from my sim. How can I do this?

Comment: What is your iOS release ?

Comment: iOS 9, iPhone 6S.

Answer (score 1):

iOS can't write to your SIM card, so you won't be able to do this on an iPhone. You have two options: find a friend with a phone that can write to SIM cards, install your SIM in their phone and erase it; or, just get a new SIM card from your carrier.

Comment: It's SIM card is also a Nano type, so we can not place it in another phone and delete the contact. I don't know why they do not fix this bug!!